# I Set ForceCommand on a server, now I can't SSH in

Tags: ssh

I set a ForceCommand in the `sshd` config file to a script that has an error. Thus execution of the script fails and the `SSH` connection is closed immediately after.

I can `SSH` as root (though the script still runs and fails, booting me off), and have tried the following:

```
ssh root@server -t "sed '/ForceCommand/d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; systemctl restart sshd
```

Though it seems to not have worked.

I've searched for a solution but can't find similar issues. Maybe I just don't know the correct keywords.

Comment: Log in from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Your sed command is missing **-i** (edit file in place) switch, which means that Sed didn't delete the line that contains **ForceCommand** string. Try with:

```
ssh root@server -t "sed -i '/ForceCommand/d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: if it was so easy to circumvent a `ForceCommand` option, it wouldn't be called `ForceCommand` in the first place...